# How to use access limiter on interface?

Tags: typescript, interface

When I tried to change access limiter on interface, then typescript emit the error. 'can not appear in type member.'
I removed access limiter on interface and then implemented interface.
And tried to change access limiter on class.

```
interface car {
  private speed: number;
}
```

this is not worked.

```
  interface car {
      speed: number;
    }
```

this is worked.

```
 class MyCar implements car {
      private speed: number;
    }
```

this is not worked.

```
class MyCar implements car {
  public speed: number;
}
```

this is worked.

Can not interface have access limiter? 
or
Can not implemented interface have access limiter on class? private or protected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access modifiers are not valid on interfaces. An interface is about the public members a class exposes. A private member is an implementation detail and thus should not matter to the public interface a class exposes.

This restriction applies to other modern OOP languages, C# and Java don't allow access modifiers on interfaces either.